# Problema en ASP.NET CORE MVC al guardar datos relacionados de dos modelos

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Tengo un problema al guardar datos relacionados de dos modelos, el primer modelo es:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ExamenApp.Models
{
    public class Pregunta
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Titulo { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("TipoPregunta")]
        public int TipoPreguntaId { get; set; }

        public TipoPregunta TipoPregunta { get; set; } = new TipoPregunta();
    }
}
```

el segundo modelo es:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ExamenApp.Models
{
    public class TipoPregunta
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

este es el controldor de Pregunta.cs:

```
using ExamenApp.Data;
using ExamenApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class PreguntaController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public PreguntaController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Pregunta
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var preguntas = _context.Pregunta.Include(p => p.TipoPregunta);
        return View(await preguntas.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Pregunta/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["TipoPreguntaId"] = new SelectList(_context.TipoPregunta, "Id", "Descripcion");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Pregunta/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Titulo,TipoPreguntaId")] Pregunta pregunta)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(pregunta);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["TipoPreguntaId"] = new SelectList(_context.TipoPregunta, "Id", "Descripcion", pregunta.TipoPreguntaId);
        return View(pregunta);
    }

    // GET: Pregunta/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var pregunta = await _context.Pregunta.FindAsync(id);
        if (pregunta == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ViewData["TipoPreguntaId"] = new SelectList(_context.TipoPregunta, "Id", "Descripcion", pregunta.TipoPreguntaId);
        return View(pregunta);
    }

    // POST: Pregunta/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Titulo,TipoPreguntaId")] Pregunta pregunta)
    {
        if (id != pregunta.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(pregunta);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PreguntaExists(pregunta.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["TipoPreguntaId"] = new SelectList(_context.TipoPregunta, "Id", "Descripcion", pregunta.TipoPreguntaId);
        return View(pregunta);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var pregunta = await _context.Pregunta.FindAsync(id);
        if (pregunta == null)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
        _context.Pregunta.Remove(pregunta);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    private bool PreguntaExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Pregunta.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }

}
```

y tengo la vista Create del Controlador Pregunta.cs:

```
@model ExamenApp.Models.Pregunta

<h2>Crear nueva pregunta</h2>

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Titulo" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Titulo" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Titulo" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TipoPreguntaId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="TipoPreguntaId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TipoPreguntaId as SelectList"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="TipoPreguntaId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Volver al índice</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

tengo datos almacenados en el modelo tipo de pregunta, y en la vista create del modelo pregunta al momento de agregar el titulo y seleccionar de la lista desplegable y luego dar en el boton crear no guarda nada y se mantiene en dicha vista Create del controlador Pregunta.cs, no sé si estoy haciendo algo mal y podrian ayudarme a resolver este inconveniente que puede que sea muy facil de corregir, pero no encuentro la solución y aun soy muy inexperto en la codificación.